# How to mock "create" method of CuratorFramework using jmockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-zookeeper, jmockit, apache-curator

I am using Netflix Curator library as I am working with Zookeeper. And now I am trying to write junit test for my code base so I need to mock some of the codes for Curator library. I am using jmockit library for mocking.

This is my below code which creates a simple znode in the zookeeper.

```
CuratorFramework client = CuratorClient.createSimple("locahost:2181");
client.start();

// line 1
client.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().forPath("/hello");
```

Now I am trying to mock `create` method of `CuratorFramework` using `jmockit` so that it doesn't create the actual znode in Zookeeper.

But not able to understand how can I mock it prorperly?

```
    new MockUp<CuratorFramework>() {
        @Mock
        public CreateBuilder create() {

            // what should I return here so that line 1 doesn't
            // create actual znode in zookeeper.
        }
    };
```

Here is the [CuratorFramework code](https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-framework/src/main/java/org/apache/curator/framework/CuratorFramework.java) and its [implementation](https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-framework/src/main/java/org/apache/curator/framework/imps/CuratorFrameworkImpl.java)

Any suggestions will be of great help?

Comment: The result of the create() method would have to be a mock and so on and so on. This seems like a rat's nest to me. What's the reason for mocking the CuratorFramework instance?

Comment: Note that `CuratorFramework` is a Java interface, so what you really need is to either mock its implementation (`CuratorFrameworkImpl`) or to mock `CuratorClient.createSimple` so it returns the implementation created by the JMockit mock-up (which can be obtained by calling `getMockInstance()` on the mock-up object).

Comment: @Randgalt I have my code base which creates and delete znodes in zookeeper and I am writing junit test for all my code base so if I run my junits then those create and delete will actually create and delete znodes for me in the zookeeper through junits and that's what I am trying to avoid by writing junits.

Comment: @Rogerio: By any chance can you provide an example how would I do that? I know you might need to take a look into the code which I have provided above. I apologize  for that but any help will be appreciated as I am still in the learning process of jmockit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would recommend the official JMockit documentation; there are many examples there.